# Python threading calls the method multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have to curl a website and display a message if the header status is not 200. The logic works fine, but I'm facing trouble with calling the method once.

The threading.Time is supposed to call the method **ONCE** every 20 seconds but apparently, it calls it multiple times. Could someone please tell me how can I make it call the *method once every 20 seconds*?

```
import requests
import threading
def check_status(url):
  while True:
    status = requests.get(url)
    if status.status_code != 200:
       print('faulty')

def main():
  threading.Timer(2.0, check_status, args=('https://www.google.com',)).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Remove the `while True:` because this is a loop and is making the request many times - you do not break out of the loop ever.

Comment: @Chris if I remove it the code runs only once. I have to run it infinitely

Comment: As in every 20 seconds?

Comment: @Chris yes, every 20 seconds.

Comment: The answer by @Rishav is what I would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new timer after you finish the old one.

```
import requests
import threading

def check_status(url): 
    status = requests.get(url)
    if status.status_code != 200:
        print('faulty')
    threading.Timer(2.0, check_status, args=('https://www.google.com',)).start()


def main():
    threading.Timer(2.0, check_status, args=('https://www.google.com',)).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every 20 seconds, you are creating a thread that enters an infinite loop which checks the HTTP status. Even if you did not use threading.Time, you would still get multiple prints. Remove the while loop and it will work as you expect.

**Update**

My mistake, looking at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

`Time` will execute the function after the time has passed. Then it will exit. What you need to do, is have `time.sleep` inside the while loop, and call the function just once inside your main.

Comment: the thread should the call the method every 20 seconds. If I remove the While loop it runs only once

Comment: Either use `time.sleep`, or what @Rishav has suggested.